# Show all roles in View with Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to show all roles existing in the DB. So in my controller i got this :

```
        public ActionResult RoleIndex()
    {
        foreach (string role in Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(role);
            Console.Write(role);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

It show all the roles so it's good. But now i want to show this in the view, how can i do that ? ViewBag, ViewData ? What is the best, because i have no access to the model of Roles.

Thank per advence and sorry for my english =/

PokeRstarr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel class:

```
public class RoleIndexViewModel
{
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate the `Roles` property of this class in your controller and return it to your view:

```
public ActionResult RoleIndex()
{
    var model = new RoleIndexViewModel { Roles = Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList() };
    return View( model );
}
```

In your view, expose the model passed and print it out:

```
@model Namespace.RoleIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Roles";
}

@foreach(var role in Model.Roles)
{
    @role <br />
}
```

Comment: OP, this is a good answer for your question and it promotes the use of strongly typed view models.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to use View Model instead of ViewBag.
Good example is [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3).

Comment: @kspearrin already provided a good example for the specific question

Answer (score -1):

Store you roles in ViewData

```
ViewData["roles"] = [String[]] Roles.GetAllRoles();
return View("myView");
```

In your View

```
<% foreach (string role in (string[] ViewData["roles"]) %>
<li><% role %>
```

Comment: Although this is possible, please do not use ViewData. Use a properly typed ViewModel class.